# is there a way to combine multiple jupyter notebooks into one?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i am trying to combine multiple jupyter notebooks into one.
for instance, copy the content of nb1.ipynb and nb2.ipynb to nb_all.ipynb.

I've searched [jupyter doc](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/preprocessors.html?highlight=clearoutput#nbconvert.preprocessors.ClearOutputPreprocessor).

there seems to be not an existing api to do this.

any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nbmerge allows you to do that (install via pip)

```
nbmerge nb1.ipynb nb2.ipynb > nb_all.ipynb
```